# Visual Studio 2015 Asp.net Core Razor syntax highlighting

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I create an Asp.net Core Web Application none of the syntax seems to get recognized.
 I don't have this problem when creating mvc 5 application.
How can I resolve this issue?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After starting VS in safe mode everything seemed to work, So I disabled some extensions one by one and the problem was caused by Resharper.
I guess my version of Resharper isn't compatible with asp.net core.